# How to access a list and dictionary in same for loop at template level in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a function in `view.py` which returns two variables i.e. a dictionary named `ca` and a list named `categories`:

```
def eventcateg_detail(request):
    ca = EventTypeCategory.objects.values()
    categories =[]
    for i in range(0, len(ca)):
       pk_sub = ca[i]['sub_categ_id']
       if (pk_sub!=None):
          category = EventTypeCategory.objects.get(id = pk_sub)
          category = category.name
          categories.append(category)
    return render(request,"events/categ.html",{
      'obj': ca,
      'categ' :categories
      })
```

`categ` returns:

```
[u'Critical in list', u'Information in list', u'Amit Pal in list']
```

My `categ.html` is:

```
<thead>
        <tr><th>{% trans "Name Category" %}</th><th>{% trans " Message" %}</th><th>{% trans "Sub-categories" %}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for obj in obj %}
        <tr>

            <td>{{ obj.name }}</td><td> {{ obj.Message_slug }}</td><td></td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My output should be:

```
Event Category  Event Message   Sub-categories
Critical            critical    critical in list
Information         information information in list
Amit Pal            amit-pal    amit pal in list
```

Sub categories contain the data coming from the list. I am getting `Event Category` (using `obj.name`) and `Event Message` (using `obj.Message_slug`) right but I'm not able to find any way to put sub-categories also in the same `td` and the same for loop (look at the template).

Comment: Anonymous down-voters, why the hate? This is not a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at this: [Django, category and subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429410/django-category-and-subcategories)

This will probably require some changes to your model but will simplify your code a lot.

**UPDATE**

I will answer your first question then :)

You can nest for loops so in your case:

```
<thead>
    <tr><th>{% trans "Name Category" %}</th><th>{% trans " Message" %}</th><th>{% trans "Sub-categories" %}</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for obj in obj %}
    <tr>

        <td>{{ obj.name }}</td><td> {{ obj.Message_slug }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for i in categ %}
                  {{ i }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

However! The above code points to a weakness in your eventcateg_detail method. The list that you create does not tell which parent-category the list item belongs to so for each parent object all items will be printed.

If you know that there will always be a one-to-one relationship and there will always be one child only you can create a dictionary instead

Also, I believe that your initial code can be simplified:

```
def eventcateg_detail(request):
        ca = EventTypeCategory.objects.all()
        categories ={}
        for cat in ca:
            if cat.sub_categ_id:

               #Since the ca queryset already contains all items you can use that to get the child category
               category = ca.objects.get(id=cat.sub_categ_id)

               #Add to dictionary. NOTE: If you ever get more than one sub-category 
               #you need to build a list of sub-categories before adding it to the dict.
               categories[cat.id] = category.name
        return render(request,"events/categ.html",{ 'obj': ca, 'categ' :categories})
```

In your template you do this:

```
<thead>
<tr>
     <th>{% trans "Name Category" %}</th>
     <th>{% trans " Message" %}</th><th>{% trans "Sub-categories" %}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for o in obj %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ o.name }}</td><td> {{ o.Message_slug }}</td>
    <td>
        {% for key, value in categ.items %}
              {% ifequal key o.id %}
               {{ value }}
              {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>

</tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Comment: Thanks for giving reply. but my question is different from that one. I am not able to find out ow put a list between already a for loop

Comment: Can you be more specific about how that answer is not working for your question?  Right off hand it looks like a good answer to me, so perhaps there's something we're missing about your requirement.

Comment: I have tried to guess what you are after. See my update above.